# PHP Store Selected HTML form item in PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, dynamic

I am creating a locker registration web application. I have a page called studentdata.php that displays student information fetched from a search query (completed).

The student data page shows name, email, student ID, program/field of study.  Next to it is a div that has another form.  The form has a drop down list that shows the available lockers for that student. What makes a locker available:
It is assigned to their program and has a studID of 0 (means there is no student assigned to it).

**What I want:** When I select one of the lockers in the drop down it dynamically displays the combination for that locker and the section that locker is in (i.e 1A) in two input fields below the drop down list - this information is stored in the table where I originally retrieved the locker numbers.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $studID = substr($url, strpos($url, "=") + 1);

$db_handle = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pickles") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - it's location of the mysql server, usually localhost
        root - your username
        third is your password

        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */

    mysql_select_db("lockers",$db_handle) or die(mysql_error());
    /* tutorial_search is the name of database we've created */

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE studID = $studID"); 
    ?>
<div class="container">
  <header> <a href="#"><img src="images/headmast.png" alt="Insert Logo Here" width="686" height="180" id="Insert_logo" /></a> </header>
  <div id="data1">
  <form id ="studData" name="studData" action="update.php" medthod="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Student Details</legend>
      <?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
  echo '<ol>';
   echo '<li>';
  echo '<label for=studid>Student ID</label>';
  echo '<input id=studid name=studid type=text value='.$row['studID'].'>';
  echo '</il>';
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<label for=fname>First Name</label>';
  echo '<input id=fname name=fname type=text value='.$row['firstName'].'>';
  echo '</il>';
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<label for=fname>Last Name</label>';
  echo '<input id=lname name=lname type=text value='.$row['lastName'].'>';
  echo '</il>';
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<label for=email>Email</label>';
  echo '<input id=email name=email type=text value='.$row['email'].'>';
  echo '</il>';
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<label for=progam>Program</label>';
  echo '<input id=progam name=progam type=text value='.$row['program'].'>';
  echo '</il>';
  echo '</ol>';
  $program = $row['program'];  //get name of program 
  } 
  ?>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" class="fButton"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <form id="locker" name="locker" action="" method="post" >
    <fieldset>
      <input type="button" onclick="show()" value="Add Locker"/>
      <div id="addlocker" style="display:none;"> 
      <!--
      query lockers where $program = program parsed in & student id is equal to 0 (this makes it available)
      get select list to 10
      populate select list    -->  <br/>
      <legend>Lockers Available: </legend>
      <select size="10" name="lockerSelect" multiple="yes" style="width:200px;">
      <?php
      $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lockers WHERE progName = '$program' && studID = 0") or die($result1."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
  {
     echo '<option value=\"'.$row1['lockerScan'].'">'.$row1['lockerNo'].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';

      ?>
      </div><!--end of add locker section-->
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: you can put those values inside a javascript variable and update the fields onclick of the locker select.

Comment: you can use Ajax to dynamically change select box value....

Comment: I thought of AJAX but I do not know the code nor do I fully understand the process.